# Error: Liquid syntax error: Unknown tag -- variable scope?

Tags: scope, jekyll, liquid, templating

I'm trying to determine which css class to give a div based on the category of a post, but I keep getting a `Error: Liquid syntax error: Unknown tag` on the variable that I created.

```
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <!-- Figuring out which css class to give the cards -->
    {% assign card_class = "" %}
    {% if page.category == 'code' %}
      {% assign card_class = "card-code" %}
    {% else %}
      {% assign card_class = "card-general" %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <div class="paper-card {% card_class %}">
        <h3>
          <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </h3>
        <p class="post-excerpt"><span class="post-meta">{{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</span>{{ post.excerpt | strip_html }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

So `{% card_class %}` throws an error. Is it out of scope? Is there a way to get that value into the class attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag syntax(`{% if t in toto %}` or `{% comment %}`) is not appropriate to output.

You need to use the output syntax `{{ card_class }}`.